# Less debugging - similar to sass

Tags: debugging, sass, less

Is there a way to debug less generated files similar to using :debug_info option in sass?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately not.

The only way you can do it is to debug less.js or dotless whilst it is compiling your file.